# CSS Hover 1 Div Affects Other non-Child Divs

Tags: html, css

Here is some mock code.  Basically I have no control over the table elements ONLY the div's inside the td's.  I need to be able to hover over any of the div's in the row and they all hover to the same state.  Can this be done?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sthompson/0nzszu10/)

HTML and CSS:

```css
.one {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

.two {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}

.three {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}


/*.one:hover, .two:hover, .three:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}*/

.row1:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="row1 one">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="row1 two">
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="row1 three">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does "hover to the same state" mean?

Comment: So hovering over any of the div .one .two. three would all hover to the row1:hover state.  Hope that states it better.

Comment: He means that all 3 *cousin* divs become same colour

Comment: Yes.  Thank you @kumar_harsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSS [there is no parent selector yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/1529630). Therefore, you can't do this directly.

However, you can try using `:hover` on the nearest common ancestor:

```css
tr:hover .row1 {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: #0000FF;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
.two {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
.three {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
}
tr:hover .row1 {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="row1 one"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="row1 two"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="row1 three"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note it's not exactly the same: if you hover the border between two cells, they will change color even if you aren't hovering any `.row1`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible using just CSS, given that you have **no** control / access whatsoever to the table or tr above. If you **do** have some access (or can say for sure that the divs will be wrapped in a **tr**, try this code:

(basically, put a rule on the grandfather `tr`)

```
tr:hover > td > div {
  background-color: black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zbqzu21r/

---

*Weird idea:*

You have the parent `tr` which you cannot control. Try making a `table` and nesting it inside the `td`. I'm assuming you can easily control anything done on this `table`. So, put your selectors on this table, and be done with it.

```css
.mytable:hover tr > td > .row1 {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <table class="mytable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="row1 one">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="row1 two">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="row1 three">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```